# How to access a "geoprocessing value object" when a row in ValueTable is empty (Python Toolbox)

Tags: arcpy, python-toolbox, value-table

I have a tool with a ValueTable consisting of two columns - text (GPString) and layer (GPFeatureLayer).
When I fill the parameter with desired values (field names in the first column, some feature layers in the second column, I can run the tool.

Problem is that not every row is filled with a layer, so some rows have the field names only. The second row of the value table then returns:

1. a geoprocessing **Layer** object if it has been filled with a feature layer or
2. a geoprocessing **value** object if it has not been filled with a feature layer.

It looks like this:

[image: tool]

I have a problem accessing the values row by row - I want to process all the rows with filled feature layer:

```
...
def getParameterInfo(self):
    """Define parameter definitions"""
    param0 = parameter("lokality", "Lokality", "GPFeatureLayer")
    param1 = parameter("value_table", "Atributy a FeatureLayery", "GPValueTable", "Optional")

    param1.columns = [["String", "Atribut"], ["GPFeatureLayer", "Limity"]]

 def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
    lokality = parameters[0].valueAsText
    valuetable = parameters[1].value

    for v in valuetable:
       # if v[1] has been filled, it is a geoprocessing layer object. I can check e.g. its name and continue
       if v[1].name:   
          do something

       # if v[1] has not been filled, it is an empty(?) geoprocessing value object, I don´t know how to handle this empty row
```

How can I check if a layer has been filled and process rows with filled layers only?

Comment: Try something like `if v[1] is None:` or `if v[1] == None:` Does that work?

Comment: Edit: not a LayerObject and ValueObject but "geoprocessing Layer object" and "geoprocessing value object". Interesting that Layer object is with a capital L and value object is not. Question updated.

Comment: `if not v[1]:`, `if v[1] is None:` nor `if v[1] == None` not working... the empty GPFeatureLayer returns "something" even if it hasn´t been filled with a feature layer... that´s the problem

Comment: I could possibly put the `if v[1].name:` to try-except block, so if v[1] was a layer object, it should go on, otherwise it would cast an exception. But I wouldn´t be much happy with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was not able to test if the returned object was a geoprocessing Layer object or a geoprocessing value object so I put `if v[1].name` into try-except block and it works.

```
for v in valuetable:
   try:
      if v[1].name:             
         ...do something with the layer

   except:
      ...do something else or don´t do anything (pass)
```